# Выразить одно выражение массива через другие

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите, есть массив и переменная

```
$scope.number = 45;
$scope.array = [
{ key1:'value1', key2:'value2', key3:'value3', key4: 'value4' },
{...},
{...},
];
```

стоит задача получить значение key4 как отношение key3 к $scope.number
реально ли это, и как это сделать в синтаксисе angular 1.6